# How can I save .xlsm file in read-only format using .Net

Tags: c#, xlsm

How do I save my `.xlsm` file in read-only format in a shared drive using .Net code. When I open it is showing as read-only. But after saving, when I open I was able to edit.

I need to have read-only format while saving. please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the IsReadOnly property on the File object

from the msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.isreadonly.aspx):

```
    // Sets the read-only value of a file.
    public static void SetFileReadAccess(string FileName, bool SetReadOnly)
    {
        // Create a new FileInfo object.
        FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(FileName);

        // Set the IsReadOnly property.
        fInfo.IsReadOnly = SetReadOnly;

    }
```